# How to pass joined variable to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Laravel seems to have changed several times on syntax and how to do things, so it's difficult to find a modern solution for the problems as a new Laravel developer.

I am trying to display an **Album** object in the **view-album.blade.php** file and JOIN another table(/model) which is called **AlbumImages**. The **AlbumImages** holds the **url** (*for the image path*) and **album_id** property while the **Album** itself holds the other data such as **title** and so on.

This function used to display the **Album** *correctly* before I joined the two tables (in **AlbumController.php**):

```
public function displayAlbum(Album $album) {
    return view('view-album', ['album' => $album]);
}
```

Route in **web.php**:

```
Route::get('/album/{album}', [AlbumController::class, "displayAlbum"])->middleware('auth');
```

The problem is that I want to join the two tables in order to access the Album images which are stored in the public image folder and return the correct images to the view (using the **url** column in the **album_images** table).

I've tried this (**AlbumController.php**):

```
public function displayAlbum(Album $album) {
    $album_combined = DB::table('albums')
        ->join('album_images', 'albums.id', '=', 'album_images.album_id')
        ->select('albums.*', 'album_images.*')->get();

    return view('view-album', ['album' => $album_combined]);
}
```

And this (**Album.php** model):

```
public function getAlbumImages() {
    return $this->hasMany(AlbumImages::class, 'album_id', 'id');
}
```

These solutions doesn't work and the question is how to do this method correctly and should it be done in the `Album` model function or inside of the **AlbumController.php** file?

Comment: you have to use Laravel relation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many in a proper way

Comment: This is what I read but was confused how to do the logic (in Controller or Model) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete solution using Laravel Eloquent Models & Relationships, hopefully this will give you a clear idea on what you can do and how to achieve the results you are looking for:

**Album Model:**

```
// bigInteger: id (AUTO_INCREMENT)
// string: name
public function album_images(){
    return $this->hasMany(AlbumImage::class);
}
```

**AlbumImage Model**:

```
// bigInteger: id (AUTO_INCREMENT)
// bigInteger: album_id
// string: image
public function album(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Album::class);
}
```

**AlbumController**:

```
public function displayAlbum(Album $album) {
    $album->load('album_images');
    return view('view-album', compact('album'));
}
```

***view-album* (VIEW)**:

```
<h1>{{$album->name}}</h1>
@foreach($album->album_images as $key=> $album_image)
    <p> {{$key}} - <img src="{{$album_image->image}}"> </p>
@endforeach
```

You can nest this further as needed.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was seeking for!